# MIPS registers regex

Tags: regex, string-matching

Im working in a mips assembly parser, using yacc and lex and I need to recognize the registers in the given instructions. That registers can be:

- `$t0,$t1,...$t31`
- `$zero`
- `r0,r1,...,r31`
- `R0,R1,...,R31`

I tried to do the first part (`$t0,...,$t31` and `R0,...$R31`), but it has not worked. My regex is `(\$t|R)([1|2][0-9]|3[0-1]|[0-9])`. As you can see in the image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYamJ.png), the regular expression matchs `R5` in the `R56` register, and this is not desired. How can I solve this problem?

[image: Regex test from RegExr]

Comment: you need word-boundary `\b` :- **[`(\$t|\bR)([1|2][0-9]|3[0-1]|[0-9])\b`](https://regex101.com/r/rK6bA0/1)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use:

```
((?:\$t|[rR])(?:[12]?[0-9]|3[01]))\b|(\$zero)
```

to match:

- `$t` or `R` or `r` followed by a number from 0 to 32 (thanks to the word boundary `\b`)
- `$zero`

See [live demo](https://regex101.com/r/pM3pL8/1).